# Python custom class indexing

Tags: python, indexing

Is it possible to make a class in python that can be indexed with square brackets but not derived from a different indexed type?

I'm interested in making a class with optional indexes, that would behave like this:

```
class indexed_array():
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values

    def __sqb__(self, indices):   #This is a made up thing that would convert square brackets to a function
        if len(indices) == 2:
            return self.values[indices[0]][indices[1]]
        elif len(indices) == 1:
            return self.values[indices[0]][0]

myarray = indexed_array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
print myarray[1, 1]     # returns 5
print myarray[1]        # returns 4
```

Is there a real method like my `__sqb__`? Alternatively, can you index a custom class another way?

Comment: You are looking for `__getitem__`

Comment: Yes. You are looking for `__getitem__`. See here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names. However, it looks like you just want to reinvent  `numpy` array.

Comment: You would be needing `__getitem__` and `__index__` magic functions. Also check: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0357/

Comment: `__getitem__` looks like just what I wanted. @juanpa.arrivillaga does numpy allow for having a default index like my example?

Comment: What do you mean by "default index"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga by "default index" I believe @ericksonia means the way that `myarray[1]` returns `values[1][0]` (not `values[1]`)

Comment: In that case, no. Indices are ordered and are accessed in order.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are need to implement `__getitem__`.  Be aware that a *single index will be passed as itself*, while *multiple indices will be passed as a tuple*.

Typically you might choose to deal with this in the following way:

```
class indexed_array:
    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        # convert a simple index x[y] to a tuple for consistency
        if not isinstance(indices, tuple):
            indices = tuple(indices)

        # now handle the different dimensional cases
        ...
```