# Python - Access a list from a class using instance[]

Tags: python, class, object, instance

So I have this code :

```
class matrix:
    def __init__(self, matriceOrigine: list) -> None:
        self.length = len(matriceOrigine)
        self.matrice = list(matriceOrigine)

    def transpose(self) -> list:
        pass

    def transition(self, lam: float) -> list:
        pass
```

And when I create an instance, like this :

```
foo = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
foo2 = matrix(foo)
```

To access a value (like 3 for example), I know I should do

```
foo2.matrice[0][2]
```

and I would like to know how to access it using

```
foo2[0][2]
```

and still use

```
foo2.transpose()
foo2.length
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How about making it a subclass of `list`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python custom class indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686020/python-custom-class-indexing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the `__getitem__` function to allow for custom indexing:

```py
def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self.matrice.__getitem__(index)
```