# how to make a class with functions dictionary

Tags: python

I need to create a class whose object will return the same values ​​when

```py
test_class.test_variable
```

and

```py
test_class['test_variable']
```

Please let me know if this is possible and if so, how.

Comment: sure, just implement `__getitem__`

Comment: Can you please see if this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627405/understanding-getitem-method

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686020/python-custom-class-indexing

Comment: It is possible.  You do it by subclassing `dict` and overriding `__getattr__()` to call `__getitem__()`.  I've seen it done by programmers who reckon that emulating Lua tables in Python is nicer than using Python dictionaries as-is. I've never seen an attempt that didn’t have bugs or gotchas. I won't  attempt to write a full implementation because (a) I don't know how to avoid the gotchas and (b) it's  a very bad idea. Do you really *need* to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getattr` to lookup an attribute by name, and use that to implement `__getitem__` for your class.

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, var):  
        self.var = var
    def __getitem__(self, s):
        return getattr(self, s)

>>> t = test(5)
>>> t.var
5
>>> t['var']
5
```